# Use tkinter based PySimpleGUI as root user via pkexec

Tags: python, tkinter, pysimplegui, polkit

I want to show a GUI Window (`PySimpleGUI` which is based on `tkinter`) as root user.
I'm using `pkexec` for that. Using GNU/Linux Debian stable.

But I got the error

```
no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I understand that a bit. But I don't know how to solve it. I tried to set `DISPLAY = ":0.0"` but this doesn't work either.

```
couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

This is my test call include setting `DISPLAY`.

```
pkexec python3 -c "import PySimpleGUI as sg;import os;os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0';sg.Window(title='title', layout=[[]], margins=(200, 100)).read()"
```

This is the full error output

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10075, in read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 10146, in _read
    self._Show()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 9886, in _Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16817, in StartupTK
    _get_hidden_master_root()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI.py", line 16704, in _get_hidden_master_root
    Window.hidden_master_root = tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2270, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"
```

Comment: Try running `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY python3 '<path to py file>'`. For more info look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627007/456156)

Comment: @thelizzard This works for my example. Thanks. But when using `os.execvp()`to start `pkexec` it doesn't work anymore. I'll investigate.

Comment: I had the this issue a few weeks ago but I used `os.system` instead of `os.execvp`. Is there a specific reason for why you are using `os.execvp`?

Comment: Yes because execvp does replace the existing process instead of just starting a new child process.

Comment: @TheLizzard Please post your comment as answer and I will accept. [Here is a follow up question about the combined use with `os.execvp()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74841444/4865723).