# Use os.execvp() to call Python script (with Tkinter based GUI) via pkexec and setting environment variables before

Tags: python, environment-variables, polkit

This is a follow-up question of [Use tkinter based PySimpleGUI as root user via pkexec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74840452/4865723).

I have a Python GUI application. It should be able to run as user and as root. For the latter I know I have to set `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY` to get a GUI application work under root. I use `pkexec` to start that application as root.

I assume the problem is how I use `os.getexecvp()` to call `pkexec` with all its arguments. But I don't know how to fix this. In the linked previous question and answer it works when calling `pkexec` directly via bash.

For that example the full path of the script should be`/home/user/x.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# FILENAME need to be x.py !!!
import os
import sys
import getpass
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def main_as_root():
    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74840452
    cmd = ['pkexec',
           'env',
           f'DISPLAY={os.environ["DISPLAY"]}',
           f'XAUTHORITY={os.environ["XAUTHORITY"]}',
           f'{sys.executable} /home/user/x.py']

    # output here is
    # ['pkexec', 'env', 'DISPLAY=:0.0', 'XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority', '/usr/bin/python3 ./x.py']
    print(cmd)

    # replace the process
    os.execvp(cmd[0], cmd)


def main():
    main_window = sg.Window(title=f'Run as "{getpass.getuser()}".',
                            layout=[[]], margins=(100, 50))
    main_window.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'root':
        main_as_root()  # no return because of os.execvp()

    # else
    main()
```

Calling that script as `/home/user/x.py root` means that the script will call itself again via `pkexec`. I got this output (self translated to English from German).

```
['pkexec', 'env', 'DISPLAY=:0.0', 'XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority', '/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/x.py']
/usr/bin/env: „/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/x.py“: File or folder not found
/usr/bin/env: Use -[v]S, to takeover options via #!
```

For me it looks like that the `python3` part of the command is interpreted by `env` and not `pkexec`. Some is not as expected while interpreting the `cmd` via `os.pkexec()`.

But when I do this on the shell it works well.

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY python3 /home/user/x.py
```

Comment: Try splitting `f'{sys.executable} /home/user/x.py'` into 2 arguments: `f'{sys.executable}'` and `'/home/user/x.py'`. I am not sure if that will work. Also given that the problem isn't coming from `tkinter`, I suggest removing the `tkinter` tag from the question

Comment: Great! That was the problem. A simple typo-like bug and not a fundamental lack of understanding the technique. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: I am lazy and don't have the time to post an answer :P

Answer (score 0):

Based on @TheLizzard comment.
The approach itself is fine and has no problem.

Just the last element in the command array `cmd`. It should be splitted.

```
cmd = ['pkexec',
       'env',
       f'DISPLAY={os.environ["DISPLAY"]}',
       f'XAUTHORITY={os.environ["XAUTHORITY"]}',
       f'{sys.executable}',
       '/home/user/x.py']
```